# How to find second last record from the table using SQL query?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have student table and there is 10 record in this table. But I want to find out the second last record and I have only table name so how can I found that record?

here is my query .

```
select * 
from student 
order by primarykey desc LIMIT 1,1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms you are using?

Comment: In mySQL that should work fine, it will fetch you the second last row.

Comment: i am using Microsoft SQL server Management Studio 2012  Jibin Balachandran

Comment: Then you can check my answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query:

```
 select top 1 * from [Your_Table_Name] where [Your_Table_Primary_Name] in
     (select top 3 [Your_Table_Primary_Name] from [Your_Table_Name] order by
      [Your_Table_Primary_Name] desc) 
order by [Your_Table_Primary_Name] asc
```

Description

---

**1.** first you need to select last three records using bellow syntax

```
 select top 3 [Your_Table_Primary_Name] 
 from [Your_Table_Name] 
 order by [Your_Table_Primary_Name] desc
```

**2.** after then you need to select first record using bellow syntax

```
 select top 1 * 
 from [Your_Table_Name] 
 where [Your_Table_Primary_Name] in (***First Syntax/Above described Syntax*****) 
 order by [Your_Table_Primary_Name] asc
```

Comment: Using a window function (as shown in Jibin's answer) will be a **lot** more efficient (in a modern DBMS).

Answer (score 3):

The ANSI standard SQL method is:

```
select * 
from student 
order by primarykey desc
offset 1 row
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This is now supported in many, if not most, databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PrimaryKey DESC) AS RN
                ) X
WHERE X.RN=2
```

The sub query will reverse your result according to `primary key` and return the `row_number()` along with it, from that result set you are taking the 2nd row which will be the actual 2nd last record.

Comment: @macmoonshine That's in SQL Server, if it's mySQL OP's query is proper.It should work since he need's the  2nd last row.

Comment: That is actually standard SQL, it works in all DBMS supporting [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/) - not only SQL Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks,I have updated my answer.I don't know much about mySQL so I was not pretty sure about that.

Comment: Well, MySQL doesn't support modern SQL - but the question does nowhere say Malay is limited by that. Currently it's only tagged with `sql` which refers to standard SQL - not a specific DBMS product

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So this won't work in MySQL, right? Since it doesn't support modern SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Should it :

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(SELECT Top 2 * FROM student ORDER BY primarykey DESC) x                     
ORDER BY primarykey
```

Comment: Hi @wraith, you are not explaining much about your solution.